# NodeJS Express - "Syntax: Invalid or unexpected token" when require a jpg

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running into an issue where I try to require a .jpg image.
When Googling I thought it had something to do with Jest but now when I start from a clean project, not having Jest as a dependency I get the same error.

What can be the issue?

This is the files I'm trying to run

**server.js**

```js
// Import express framework
const express = require('express')
// Import routes
const visionAiRouter = require('./routes/vision-ai-route')
// Setup default port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000
// Create express app
const app = express()
// Vision AI Route
app.use('/ai', visionAiRouter)

// Implement route for errors
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
 console.error(err.stack)
 res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
// Start express app
app.listen(PORT, function() {
console.log(`Server is running on: ${PORT}`)
})
```

**vision-ai-route.js**

```js
// Import
const express = require('express')
const visionAi = require('../controllers/vision-ai-controller')
// Create express router
const router = express.Router()
router.get('/', visionAi.labelDetection)
// Export
module.exports = router
```

**vision-ai-controller.js**

```js
// Assets
const cat = require('./../data/cat.jpg')
// Create controller for GET request to '/users/all'
exports.labelDetection = async (req, res) => {
      // Imports the Google Cloud client library
      const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
  
      // Creates a client
      const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
    
      // Performs label detection on the image file
      const [result] = await client.labelDetection(cat);
      const labels = result.labelAnnotations;
      const stringify = JSON.stringify(labels);
      await res.json(stringify)
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^2.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
/Users/kod/Desktop/Code/Private/vision-ai/test/data/cat.jpg:1
����
^    
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kod/Desktop/Code/Private/vision-ai/test/controllers/vision-ai-controller.js:3:13)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
```

Comment: How can you use require? for the files? you have to provide full path of your image file. May be like in images folder you can place the images and make the images folder public. thanks

Comment: I'm trying to compile my brain to nodeJS from React and thinking that everything works like React ;)  @paulsm4

So in NodeJS you have to always write out the full file path and it doesn't work like React where you can write the file path relative from the file you editing?

Comment: As it sounds like you've since learned, the problem has nothing to do with the path ... it's just that "require()" doesn't mean what you apparently thought it did :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't require a non-code file as `require` is meant to load executable code. The correct equivalent would be `const cat = fs.readFileSync('./test/data/cat.jpg')`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! It worked!
Just adding that I had to edit the filepath as well (Based on the comments on my post).

Comment: The path is actually relative to the application's PWD, so you'd likely be able to pass `./test/data/cat.jpg`, but to be unambiguous, you can use `path.join(__dirname, '../test/data/cat.jpg')`. The `__dirname` global is available in all Node.js modules, and resolves to the directory that the current file resides in.